# Как сделать такую анимацию с помощью плагина skrollr?

Tags: javascript, jquery, анимация, прокрутка

Добрый день! Подскажите, пожалуйста, возможно ли сделать такую анимацию с помощью плагина skrollr (https://github.com/Prinzhorn/skrollr)? Благодарю!

```js
$(function() {
var $hor = $("#horizontal");
$("body").css('padding-bottom', $(window).width()*2);
var delta = 0;
$(window).on('scroll', function () {
  var top = $(document).scrollTop();
  var width = $(window).width();
  var lim = $hor.position().top - (delta) - ($(window).height() - $hor.outerHeight()) / 2;
  delta = Math.min(Math.max(top - lim, 0), width * 2);

  $(".horizontal:first", $hor).css({left : delta});
  $(".horizontal:last", $hor).css({left : -(width*2 - delta)});
  $("body").css({'padding-top': delta, 'padding-bottom': width*2 - delta});
});

});
```

```css
p {
  height: 500px;
}
#horizontal {
 position: relative;
 overflow: hidden;
 width: 100%;
 font-size: 3em;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 height: 250px;
}
#horizontal .horizontal {
 position: absolute;
 width: 100%;
 left: -100%;
 padding: 20px;
}
#horizontal .horizontal .h_blockquote {
 position: relative;
 width: 100%;
 margin: 0 auto;
 font-size: 24px;
 line-height: 1.3em;
 color: #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>test</p>
<div id="horizontal">
<div class="horizontal">
<div class="h_blockquote">
<div class="h_blockquote_wrap">Скрипт некорректно работает в браузере Internet Explorer. Как исправить? Скрипт некорректно работает в браузере Internet Explorer. Как исправить?</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="horizontal">
<div class="h_blockquote">
<div class="h_blockquote_wrap">Скрипт некорректно работает в браузере Internet Explorer. Как исправить? Скрипт некорректно работает в браузере Internet Explorer. Как исправить?</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<p>test</p>
```

Comment: какую именно анимацию?

Comment: Возможно, ниже результат.

Comment: Добрый. Странно, но вроде они одинаковые, в вашем вопросе скорость прокрутки меньше, а в целом так же, скролим блок, появляется текст , этот текст смещается в право за ним следует другой текст, когда текст заканчивается он поднимается выше. Вероятно попробуйте более медленно прокрутить, это уже дело тонкой настройки. Хотя вам виднее )

Answer (score 1):

Как-то так, на гитхабе есть параметры плагина, поиграйте с ними что бы добиться более точного результата.

```js
   
   var s = skrollr.init();
```

```css
.skrollable {
   position: fixed;
  z-index: 100;
}
p {
  height: 500px;
}
#horizontal {
 position: relative;
 overflow: hidden;
 width: 100%;
 font-size: 3em;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 height: 250px;
}
#horizontal .horizontal {

 width: 100%;
 padding: 20px;
}
#horizontal .horizontal .h_blockquote {
 position: relative;
 width: 100%;
 margin: 0 auto;
 font-size: 24px;
 line-height: 1.3em;
 color: #000;
}
.horizontal {

}
```

```html
<script src="http://prinzhorn.github.io/skrollr/dist/skrollr.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>test</p>
<div id="horizontal">
<div  data-300="left:0%;top:100%;" data-350="top:0%;" data-400="left:100%" class="horizontal">
<div class="h_blockquote">
<div class="h_blockquote_wrap">Скрипт некорректно работает в браузере Internet Explorer. Как исправить? Скрипт некорректно работает в браузере Internet Explorer. Как исправить?</div>
</div>
</div>
<div  data-400="left:-100%;top:100%;" data-450="top:0%;" data-500="left:0%;" data-550="top:-100%;" class="horizontal">
<div class="h_blockquote">
<div class="h_blockquote_wrap">Скрипт некорректно работает в браузере Internet Explorer. Как исправить? Скрипт некорректно работает в браузере Internet Explorer. Как исправить?</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<p>test</p>
```

Answer (score -1):

Посмотрите это решение. Там уже можно поиграть с data- атрибутами

```
<div class="text_wrap"
    data-100="left:50%;display:block; position:fixed;top:100px"
    data-650="left:100%;display:none; " 
    data-700="left:-100%;display:block; " 
    data-1050="left:50%; position:fixed;top:100px"
    data--10-end="left:50%; position:fixed; top:-1050px" >
        Скрипт некорректно работает в браузере Internet Explorer. Как исправить? Скрипт некорректно работает в браузере Internet Explorer. Как исправить?
</div>
```

http://codepen.io/DSergey/pen/vXmrkb